designing Mongo-db deployment in GCP Cloud
We are deploying mongo-db replica cluster 2 node in GCP google compute engine and we are keeping these GCE (primary mongo-db and secondary mongo-db)instances under stateful instances group (mig) and we will connect application (bigid) which is running on GKE to these mongo-db via internal application load balancer(https).
Now it looks good but i have few doubts about this design

if application try to write on db then it will go through lb but i am not sure if the request everytime will go to primary db via lb. or if there is no option available with available LB algorithm than it would be better to remove lb and directly connect to application without lb

2.for SSL/TLS configuration do we need to generate two certificate one for primary and another for secondary  if SSL termination is not happening at LB or if we dont use LB
or
if SSL is terminating at LB end then we need to assign only one SSL certificate at LB but what configuration we need to add in mongdb.conf file
if someone can guide me on the above 2 points that would be very helpful !!!

A MongoDB has no HTTP(S) interface. It is not clear where your application and the HTTP server is installed, thus focus on the MongoDB itself.
Regarding Load-Balancer
Obviously it does not make much sense when you have a load-balancer with only one node behind it. In general, you can write only to the PRIMARY node - there is no exception! You can define in your connection string or by command from which node you like to read, see Read Preference
A 2-member Replica Set does not add any high-availability, because the majority must be available to elect a PRIMARY (1 out of 2 is not the majority). But it looks like, this was not your intention to deploy the replica set. By default either node may be elected as PRIMARY. You can give priority to one member, however by default it is not determined which nodes becomes PRIMARY and which is SECONDARY.
SSL/TLS configuration
Not clear to me what you mean. You have up to three types of certificates in a MongoDB replica set / sharded cluster:

The server certificate
A client certificate which is used to authenticate the client
A client certificate which is used for internal replica set membership authentication

You could create SSL server certificates for each server, however usually you create only one and you put all host names into the Subject Alternative Name (SAN)
If you decide to use client certificate for authentication, then you must create  separate client certificate for internal membership authentication and for "normal" clients. Like above, usually you create only one client certificate membership authentication - but it would be possible to create dedicated certificates for each member. Different clients, of course required different client certificates.

thanks Wernfried for you reply and i would go with one certificate and put other node name in Subject Alternative Name.
